# is it possible to retrieve userID of the user from loginView?

Tags: asp.net

im using the loginView in asp.net like this :

```
<asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
<AnonymousTemplate>
    <a href="#login" id="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a>
</AnonymousTemplate>
<LoggedInTemplate>
    <asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" />
    <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="~/" />
</LoggedInTemplate>
```

library.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace IRELBS.Library
{
    public partial class Library : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tbxUserID.Text = Membership.GetUser.ProviderUserKey.ToString(); 
        }
    }
}
```

and library.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Library.aspx.cs" Inherits="IRELBS.Library.Library" %>

    <%@ Register Src="~/Mod/ReqPopup.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="ReqPopup" %>


    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <%--    <div class="container">
            <div class="jumbotron cent">
                <h1>Welcome</h1>
                <p>
                    to AZLearn library.
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Watch now</a> 
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Tweet it!</a>
            </div>
        </div>--%>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <h3 class="cent">Asp.net</h3>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Start Tutorial</a>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnR" runat="server" Text="Requirements" CssClass="btn btn-info pull-right" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <h3 class="cent">Java</h3>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Start Tutorial</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Requirements</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <h3 class="cent">HTML5</h3>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Start Tutorial</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Requirements</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <h3 class="cent">CSS</h3>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Start Tutorial</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Requirements</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <h3 class="cent">Asp.net</h3>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Start Tutorial</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Requirements</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <h3 class="cent">Java</h3>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Start Tutorial</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Requirements</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <h3 class="cent">HTML</h3>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Start Tutorial</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Requirements</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <h3 class="cent">CSS3</h3>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Start Tutorial</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Requirements</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbxUserID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </asp:Content>
```

is there anyway to retrieve the user id the same way or do i need to write ADO.Net codes to get the userID ?? 
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the standard FormsAuthentication you can get the ID by inspecting `Membership.GetUser.ProviderUserKey`. It will be a GUID so if you want to display it you will need to use `Membership.GetUser.ProviderUserKey.ToString`

Comment: im using membership. what im actually tryin to do is get the info of the member! but for starter, how can i use Membership.GetUser.ProviderUserKey.ToString ? where should i use it i mean?

Comment: Where would you like to display it? Inside the LoggedInTemplate?

Comment: anywhere ...like a different page maybe!

Comment: try `<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" 
            Text='<%= Membership.GetUser.ProviderUserKey.ToString %>'></asp:TextBox>`

Comment: i get a textbox which the text inside has "<%= Membership.GetUser.ProviderUserKey.ToString %>" in it!!

Comment: Hello. I have investigated this further and the variable cannot be put directly into the textbox from the design page, sorry. What you can do it put it in the code behind. So for example you could put this in the `Page_Load` event: TextBox6.text  = Membership.GetUser.ProviderUserKey.ToString

Comment: its says "Error 3'System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser()' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context" !!

Comment: Where exactly have you put it? Can you copy the surrounding code please?

Comment: in Page_Load of the page which user will be able to access after log in!

Comment: This should work which is why I am asking you to post your whole block of code please.

Comment: i have edited the code in the question...btw, thank you for your help